# Wordpress Loop With differing layouts

Tags: wordpress

I want to run a loop with the 6 latest posts on the front of my wordpress site but i want the 4th and 6th posts to have a slightly different layout than the other 4 how would i specify this in the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class names to what you need.

```
<?php $counter =0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?><!-- begin of loop -->
<?php
  ++$counter;
  if($counter == 4 or $counter == 6) {
    $postclass = 'class="different"';        
  } else { $postclass = 'normal'; }
?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php echo $postclass; ?>>
<?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?><!-- end of loop -->
```

Comment: Hi Huntz i actually need it a bit different so that if it's the 4th or 6th a different image size is shown and some other details like date and custom field are displayed so what i need is something like if is 4th or 6th then one set of layout items and if not then if not then another. I know i can do this with CSS but I'd rather do it directly. Thanks